# RichTextBox type of output & removing duplicates

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a small VB program to remove duplicate lines and empty lines from plain text.
I have the RichTextBox input but eventually I do not know what the type of the returned object is, is it an array or a list maybe ?

Also I'm trying to find the most efficient way to remove duplicate lines from big plain text(s), in Python I do it this way :

```
lines_nodupes = {} 
for elt in lines :
lines_nodupes[elt] = ""
```

Since you can not have twice the same key, no duplicates are kept in the lines_nodupes dictionnary and I can enumerate it to access the lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two properties you can use :

1. `Lines` will return an array of Strings
2. `Text` will return the entire text as a string

See [RichTextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from MSDN

If you want to do as in Python :

```
Dim noDup as new Dictionary(Of String, String)

For Each line in MyRichTextBox.Lines
    if not noDup.ContainsKey(line) then
        noDUp.add(line, "")
    End if
Next
```

You can also do (as suggested by VisualVincent in the coments) :

```
Dim noDup as new List(Of String)

For Each line in MyRichTextBox.Lines
    if not noDup.Contains(line) then
        noDUp.add(line)
    End if
Next
```

which is a bit slower but difference won't be seen unless you have a very long list of items.

Comment: Why use a dictionary? Use a `List(Of T)` and check `.Contains()`.

Comment: Because I think a Dictionary will be more efficient in terms of searching the string... `List.Contains()` will compare every item and runs in O(N), while a dictionary will check Hashcode and run at worst in O(N)

Comment: Point, but the `.Contains()` iteration doesn't take long unless the list is _extremely_ long.

Comment: I should have added that in the OP but I will be handling millions of lines sometimes. Thank you for your help really it's greatly appreciated, you really enlightened me!

Comment: then use the first option with dictionary

Comment: Will do! I'll update here when I'm done, thank you again!